# Syntax error: Expected keyword ELSE or keyword END but got keyword CASE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I run this code "Syntax error: Expected keyword ELSE or keyword END but got keyword CASE at [3:3]"

shows. How can I fix this

In addition what is the meaning of the last part [3:3]?
Moreover, If I want to use 'WITH' at the same time is there difference for it?

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN Charge='Free week extension (0.00)' THEN 'Free extension'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Free week extension (Free week extension) (x1) 0.00' THEN 'Free extension'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Free week extension'THEN 'Free extension'
  CASE WHEN Charge='1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (0.00)' THEN 'Free trial'
  CASE WHEN Charge='1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (1주 무료체험권 ( 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL )) (x1) 0.00' THEN 'Free trial'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Free Trial' THEN 'Free trial'
  CASE WHEN Charge='1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권' THEN 'Free trial'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership' THEN 'Foundation 1 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership' THEN 'Foundation 1 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership (0.00)' THEN 'Foundation 1 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership (295800.00)' THEN 'Foundation 1 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership (Foundation Membership - 1 month) (x1) 147900.00' THEN 'Foundation 1 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership (Foundation Membership - 1 month) (x1) 295800.00' THEN 'Foundation 1 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership (835200.00)' THEN 'Foundation 3 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Foundation Membership (Foundation Membership 3-month) (x1) 835200.00' THEN 'Foundation 3 month'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권' THEN '1 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (30000.00)' THEN '1 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (1 Class Pass / 1회 이용권) (x1) 30000.00' THEN '1 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (250000.00)' THEN '10 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (10 Class Pass / 10회 이용권) (x1) 125000.00' THEN '10 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (10 Class Pass / 10회 이용권) (x1) 200000.00' THEN '10 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (10 Class Pass / 10회 이용권) (x1) 250000.00' THEN '10 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (20 Class Pass / 20회 이용권) (x1) 400000.00' THEN '20 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (20 Class Pass / 20회 이용권) (x1) 450000.00' THEN '20 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (450000.00)' THEN '20 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (40 Class Pass / 40회 이용권) (x1) 800000.00' THEN '40 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='CLASS PASSES / 회수권 (800000.00)' THEN '40 Class Pass'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Influencer membership' THEN 'Influencer membership'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Influencer membership (Influencer membership (3 month)) (x1) 0.00' THEN 'Influencer membership'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권' THEN '1 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (348000.00)' THEN '1 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (1 MONTH UNLIMITED / 1개월 무제한 사용권) (x1) 0.00' THEN '1 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (1 MONTH UNLIMITED / 1개월 무제한 사용권) (x1) 298000.00' THEN '1 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (1 MONTH UNLIMITED / 1개월 무제한 사용권) (x1) 348000.00' THEN '1 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (835000.00)' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (887000.00)' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (3 MONTH UNLIMITED / 3개월 무제한 사용권 / (15% 혜택) (15% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 0.00' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (3 MONTH UNLIMITED / 3개월 무제한 사용권 / (15% 혜택) (15% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 473500.00' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (3 MONTH UNLIMITED / 3개월 무제한 사용권 / (15% 혜택) (15% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 798300.00' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (3 MONTH UNLIMITED / 3개월 무제한 사용권 / (15% 혜택) (15% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 857000.00' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (3 MONTH UNLIMITED / 3개월 무제한 사용권 / (15% 혜택) (15% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 877000.00' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (3 MONTH UNLIMITED / 3개월 무제한 사용권 / (15% 혜택) (15% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 887000.00' THEN '3 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='MONTHLY UNLIMITED MEMBERSHIPS / 월 무제한 사용권 (6 MONTH UNLIMITED / 6개월 무제한 사용권 / (20% 혜택) (20% DISCOUNT)) (x1) 1670000.00' THEN '6 Month Unlimited'
  CASE WHEN Charge='45일 챌린지 / 45 DAY CHALLENGE' THEN 'Challenge'
  CASE WHEN Charge='Challenge package (Challenge package) (x1) 746000.00' THEN 'Challenge'
  CASE WHEN Charge='2WEEK INITIATOR CHALLENGE (2WEEK INITIATOR CHALLENGE) (x1) 0.00' THEN 'Challenge' ELSE 'etc' END AS Plan_category FROM `F45_KR.GDE_transaction_W4_Oct_2022`
```

`

I tried to change the valiable name Plan_category => Charge_category and I rewrote the code but still not working.

Comment: The syntac is `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... **END**`. You are missing `END`s everywhere. Or maybe you want just one `CASE`, with multiple `WHEN` branches... Please consider narrowing down your code to just a few lines of reproducible example, along with the desired result ; it will help other help you.

Comment: All that effort waisted on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You only need the `CASE` once at the beginning of the full expression:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN Charge='Free week extension (0.00)' THEN 'Free extension'
       WHEN Charge='Free week extension (Free week extension) (x1) 0.00' THEN 'Free extension'
       WHEN Charge='Free week extension'THEN 'Free extension'
       ...
```

You could also do this to reduce some repetition in the query:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN Charge IN (
         'Free week extension (0.00)',
         'Free week extension (Free week extension) (x1) 0.00',
         'Free week extension')  THEN 'Free extension'
       WHEN Charge IN (
         '1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (0.00)',
         '1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (1주 무료체험권 ( 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL )) (x1) 0.00',
         'Free Trial',
         '1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권')  THEN 'Free trial'
       ...
```

But personally, I'd put these all in another table:

| Full_Charge_Description | Charge_Category |
| --- | --- |
| Free week extension (0.00) | Free extension |
| Free week extension (Free week extension) (x1) 0.00 | Free extension |
| Free week extension | Free extension |
| 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (0.00) | Free Trial |
| 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (1주 무료체험권 ( 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL )) (x1) 0.00 | Free Trial |
| Free Trial | Free Trial |
| 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 | Free trial |
| ... |  |

And then **JOIN** to the table.

```
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(m.Charge_Category, 'etc') Plan_Category
FROM `F45_KR.GDE_transaction_W4_Oct_2022` t
LEFT JOIN Charge_Category_Map m ON m.Full_Charge_Description = t.Charge
```

Some databases also allow you to put this data in a [Table-Value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), to include the mapping in the query but still have the JOIN option. I'm not sure on whether Big Query allows this, but here is  how it would look for SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(m.Charge_Category, 'etc') Plan_Category
FROM `F45_KR.GDE_transaction_W4_Oct_2022` t
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    ('Free extension', 'Free week extension (0.00)'),
    ('Free extension', 'Free week extension (Free week extension) (x1) 0.00'), 
    ('Free extension', 'Free week extension'),
    ('Free Trial',     '1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (0.00)'),
    ('Free Trial',     '1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권 (1주 무료체험권 ( 1 WEEK FREE TRIAL )) (x1) 0.00'),
    ('Free Trial',     'Free Trial'),
    ('Free Trial',     '1 WEEK FREE TRIAL / 1주 무료체험권'),
    ...
) AS m(Charge_Category, Full_Charge_Description) ON m.Full_Charge_Description = t.Charge
```

The advantages of using a real table for this are you can also **index** it, which can *greatly* improve performance, and that you can now treat it as data, where someone other than an expensive developer can take over entry and maintenance of the data.